# database file for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection

6 months back I wrote a rails app (craigslist scraper) and all of the code was pushed to github and then deployed to heroku. Since this time I got a new laptop and am getting back into learning code. I am trying to get the same app running locally on my machine but am getting an error that no DB is connected (( `Rails.application.database_configuration`: Could not load database configuration. No such file )) how can I download the DB file from GitHub or get the DB going again and run a fresh scrape? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run.

```
rake db:create db:migrate
```

This will create the database from your `database.yml` file, then run the migrations.

Comment: i dont even seem to have a database.yml file?

Comment: when I run that command I get: cannot load rails.application.database_configuration no such file'

Comment: /config/database.yml was in my .gitignore

Comment: Do you have a database.yml.example?

Comment: No sure what you mean ?